# Divide maven project into project with sub-projects in eclips

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have one big maven project in eclipse, I woudl like to divide it to smaller sub-projects, my question is, is there any tool which can automize that process some how? Or shoudl i do it manually?

Comment: Question is off-topic for SO. But no tools except your own hands can do that, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks tunaki for informations, i have alread found sonatype docse so i will read them.

Comment: I am not sure about tool.i have achieved using Multiple Module Projects check this link:https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html

Answer (score 1):

The first step: creating the sub-projects, you have to do by hand.
The next steps: moving the classes, can be done using standard 'move' refactorings.